# MSSQL Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff

I have the following Query in MSSQL where I need to filter if the date difference is greater than zero, but it causes an error:

*Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character* string

```
    select
       cd.customerid,
       cd.value as end_date,
       DATEDIFF(day, cd.date_string, getDate()) as diff
    from customerdetails cd
    join freetrialdate ftd
        on ftd.freetrialdateid = cd.freetrialdateid 
    where ftd.keyName = 'free_trial_45'
    and  DATEDIFF(day, cd.date_string, getDate()) > 0 -- if I add this line it causes the error
```

where the date_string is in the format of **YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm**

what could be the issue here, or how can I achieve to check the diff in days of said date vs current date?

Comment: `CONVERT` the value with a style code, `yyyy-MM-dd` is ambigous with the `datetime` data type (which you are implicitly using here). Or, better yet, don't use a `varchar` to store your date and time data, it's a ***significant*** design flaw, and use a SARGable `WHERE`: `cd.AnActualDateAndTimeValue < CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE()))`.

Comment: As @Larnu said, never store dates as strings or varchar. You have a proper date/datetime/timestamp data types to do it and avoid this kind of issues

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results

Comment: Do you have `SET DATEFORMAT DMY` in effect? Prefer to use `YYYY-DD-MMTHH:mm:ss` (note the `T` and `:ss` components) to be `DATEFORMAT`-agnostic. But, really, store dates and datetimes in their proper binary formats, `date` and `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Larnu's comment above that must not use varchar for storing date types, but the table definition can't be changed for some reason.

I found a solution to make sure that the varchar is in date format, adding **ISDATE** function on where clause helps

```sql
    select
       cd.customerid,
       cd.value as end_date,
       DATEDIFF(day, cd.date_string, getDate()) as diff
    from customerdetails cd
    join freetrialdate ftd
        on ftd.freetrialdateid = cd.freetrialdateid 
    where ftd.keyName = 'free_trial_45'
    and  ISDATE(cd.date_string) = 1
    and  DATEDIFF(day, cd.date_string, getDate()) > 0
```

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to work. You cannot decide the order that predicates will be evaluated. It may work today but it will fail at some point. Instead you should use `try_convert` for your date_string instead of the implicit conversion.